# TypeError: unhashable type: 'Node'

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have this code that finds shortest and quickest path between a source and destination

````
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, name, power, generation):
        """
        Creates Node Object

        Requires: (id = int), (name = string), (power = int), (generation = int)
        """
        self.id = ID
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.generation = generation

    def getId(self):
        """
        Gets id atribute.
        """
        return self.id

    def getName(self):
        """
        Get name atribute.
        """
        return self.name

    def getPower(self):
        """
        Get power atribute.
        """
        return self.power

    def getGeneration(self):
        """
        Get generation atribute.
        """
        return self.generation

    def allInfo(self):
        '''
        Gives a representation of each node atribiutes
        '''
        return "ID: " + str(self.id) + " | NAME: " + self.name + " | POWER: " + str(self.power) + " | GENERATION: " + str(self.generation)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''
        Sets node if equal to other id if is an instance
        '''
        if isinstance(other, Node):
            return self.id == other.id
        return False```
````

class Digraph(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    """
    Nodes is a list of the nodes in the graph.

    Edges is a dict mapping each node to a list of its children.
    """

    self.nodes = []
    self.edges = {}

def addNode(self, node):
    """
    Adds the nodes.
    """
    if node in self.nodes:
        raise ValueError('Duplicate node')
    else:
        self.nodes.append(node)
        self.edges[node] = []
```

def main(args):
    '''
    Main function that receives args as the files given in the shell to iniciate program operation
    Requires:
    args is the older for the multiple files given to be read
    Ensures:
    Creates the output file with the stations time connections
    '''

```
stations = []
conns = []

file_in = open(args[1], "r")
for line in file_in:
    if (line[0] != "#"):
        station_info = line.split(", ")
        stations.append(Node(int(station_info[0]),
                             station_info[1],
                             int(station_info[2]),
                             int(station_info[3])))
        conns.append(line.split("(")[1].split(", "))

g = Digraph()

for station in stations:
    g.addNode(station)

aux = 0

for station in stations:
    for s in conns[aux]:
        # por \r\n em mac
        pos = (int(s.replace("\n", ""))) - 1
        g.addEdge(Edge(station, stations[int(pos)]))
    aux += 1
file_in.close()

file_in = open(args[2], "r")
maxTest = len(file_in.readlines())
file_in.close()

file_in = open(args[2], "r")
file_out = open(args[3], "w")

count = 0
for line in file_in:
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    stationNames = line.split(" ")
    stop = False
    stationA = findStation(stations, stationNames[0])

    if stationA == None:
        file_out.write(stationNames[0] + " out of the network\n")
        stop = True

    stationB = findStation(stations, stationNames[1])
    if stationB == None:
        file_out.write(stationNames[1] + " out of the network\n")
        stop = True

    if stationA == stationB:
        file_out.write("Trying to connect same station (" + stationA.getName() + ", " + stationB.getName() + ")\n")
        stop = True

    if not stop:
        file_out.write(str(search(g, stationA, stationB)) + "\n")

    count += 1
    percentage = round(count * 100 / maxTest, 1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r     Progress: " + str(percentage) + "%     |     ")
    sys.stdout.write("Tested: " + str(count) + " of " + str(maxTest) + " connections!")
    sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write("\n")

file_in.close()
file_out.close()
```

```
but i'm getting this error

    C:\Users\André Ramos\Desktop\Project\Project\relayStationsGroup12>python 
    relayStations.py inputFile1.txt inputFile2.txt out.txt

    ##########################  Relay Stations  ############################

    RelayStations is running...

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "relayStations.py", line 339, in <module>
       main(sys.argv)
      File "relayStations.py", line 270, in main
       g.addNode(station)
      File "relayStations.py", line 113, in addNode
       self.edges[node] = ()
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'Node'
```

Comment: The error seems to append in code that you have not shown here, in `relayStations.py` line 113. I am afraid that the error is explicit and that you try to use a mutable type as a key in a dictionary. You have to show the `Node` class if you want further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nodes are instances of custom `Node` class:

```
Node(int(station_info[0]),
     station_info[1],
     int(station_info[2]),
     int(station_info[3]))
```

But Python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) need their keys to be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable):

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()`  method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id().

So if you want to use your Nodes as dictionary keys, you have to implement [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) magic methods for them.

Comment: But I do have a __eq__ method

Comment: You need not only `__eq__` method, but `__hash__` too.